# Do I need RubyCocoaBridge or MacRuby or both to develop in Ruby for the iPad?

Tags: iphone, ruby, ipad, macruby

I've heard both [MacRuby](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacRuby) and [Ruby CocoaBridge](http://rubycocoa.sourceforge.net/HomePage) discussed in relation to iPhone/iPad development in Ruby. Do I need one or both of these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither of those will work. The only way is with [Rhodes](http://rhomobile.com/products/rhodes/). CocoaBridge is sometimes used for testing, but can't run on an iPhone. MacRuby might be able to work one day if they add garbage collection to the iPhone OS, but it doesn't now.

Also, consider [iPhone Wax](http://www.mobileorchard.com/announcing-iphone-wax-native-uikit-iphone-apps-written-in-lua/), which uses Lua, a fairly ruby-like language.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way to use Ruby on iPhone or iPad and won't be for the foreseeable future. At least if you want your app in the appstore. See this post

[Can you develop native iPhone apps in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/219653/ruby-on-iphone)